# How to delete a specific line in a text file using user input Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I have a problem with a python 3 program. I am trying to build a function that delets a specific line in a text file using user input but can't for the life of me get it to work. Since I am a beginner i was wondering if someone more expicienced could help me with buildning the function.

Python 3 code:

```
def main():
    players = load_results_from_file("user_res.txt")
    while True:
        show_menu()
        user_choice = input("Välj alternativ: ")
        print()
        if user_choice == "1":
            show_players(players)
        elif user_choice == "2":
            add_player(players)
        elif user_choice == "3":
            save_players(players, "user_res.txt")
        elif user_choice == "4":
            del_player(players)
        elif user_choice == "5":
            break
        else:
            print("Du angav ett felaktivt val, försök igen")
    print("Ha en bra dag!")

def save_players(players, file_name):
    my_file = open(file_name, "w")
    for player in players:
        my_file.write("{};{};{};{}\n".format(player["name"], 
        player["round_1"], 
        player["round_2"], player["round_3"]))
    my_file.close()
    print("Sparat!")

def add_player(players):
    name = input("Ange namn: ")
    round_1 = input("Ange varv 1: ")
    round_2 = input("Ange varv 2: ")
    round_3 = input("Ange varv 3: ")
    players.append({
        "name": name,
        "round_1": round_1,
        "round_2": round_2,
        "round_3": round_3
     })

def show_players(players):
    print("*"*40)
    print("Mini Golf")
    print("*"*40)
    for player in players:
        print("{:15} {} {} {}".format(player["name"], player["round_1"], 
        player["round_2"], player["round_3"]))
    print()

def show_menu():
    print("Klubbmästerskap i minigolf")
    print("*"*40)
    print()
    print("Meny")
    print("*"*4)
    print("1) Visa resultat")
    print("2) Lägg till resultat")
    print("3) Spara resultat")
    print("4) Radera spelare")
    print("5) Avsluta programmet")

def load_results_from_file(file_name):
    players_list = []
    try:
        my_file = open(file_name, "r")
    except:
        my_file = open(file_name, "w").close()
        print("INFO: Ingen fil hittades, så vi skapa den!")
        return players_list

    content = my_file.read()
    for players in content.split("\n"):
        try:
            player = players.split(";")
            players_list.append({
                "name": player[0],
                "round_1": player[1],
                "round_2": player[1],
                "round_3": player[1]
             })
        except:
            pass
     return players_list


def del_player(players):
    delete_player = input("Ange spelaren du vill radera: ")
    my_file = open("user_res.txt", "r")
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    my_file.close()
    my_file = open("user_res.txt", "w")
    for line in lines:
        if delete_player not in lines:
            my_file.write(line)


main()
```

Some of the text is in swedish and I will change that if it is necessary. But the function that I can't get to work is del_player. I want the user to input the player they want to delete with delete_player but so far it don't delete anything from the text file.

Comment: Am I right with my answer? If yes what about marking the answer as accepted?

Comment: OK - ONE of the apparent problems your code had is solved. Let's solve the other one if any ... let me make some additions to my answer ...

Comment: I saw now that if i restart the program the result i inupt is deleted. Sorry that i did not notice before. I have marked your answer as accepted! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome :) . This type of problem is very common. I run into such type problem often myself - sometimes you just need someone else to look at it. Often a comparison of a string and an integer is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for sure a small TYPO marked in the source code with '#(1) !!!':

```
def del_player(players):
    delete_player = input("Ange spelaren du vill radera: ")
    my_file = open("user_res.txt", "r")
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    my_file.close()
    my_file = open("user_res.txt", "w")
    for line in lines:
        print(type(delete_player), delete_player, type(line), line) #(2) !!!
        if delete_player not in line: #(1) !!!
            my_file.write(line)
```

If this doesn't solve the problem adding a `print()` (marked #(2) !!! as above can clarify how it comes that `delete_player` is not found in `line`.